# Image displaying behind the section after using overflow hidden

Tags: html, css

I am getting the horizontal scroll when using `after` class.

If I use overflow then my image is displaying behind the first section.

Would you help me out with these issues?

**This is the `after` class which is not working. I am getting scrollbar**

```css
section {
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

.test1 {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.test1:after {
  content: "";
  background-image: url('https://www.netclipart.com/pp/m/16-165891_sale-price-tag-png-sale-icon-png.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 350px;
  height: 308px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -15%;
  right: -10%;
}
```

```html
<section style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</section>
<section class="test1">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>

</section>
```

**I am getting the output**

[image]
**My expected output**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Problem is `img` is `relative` to that div so it cut, Setting `right`
>   `0` and width to actual width of img solved that problem

```css
section {
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

.test1 {

}

.test1:after {
  content: "";
  background-image: url('https://www.netclipart.com/pp/m/16-165891_sale-price-tag-png-sale-icon-png.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
      width: 210px;
    height: 308px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -15%;
    right: 0;
 background-position: 47px center
}
```

```html
<section style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</section>
<section class="test1">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>

</section>
```

Comment: Yes, Image is displaying but why you remove right: -10%? I have to display use -10% to display half image on the screen.

Comment: @NarenVerma Use `background-position` property for that like `background-position: 47px center;`

Comment: Yes it's working. Can you update the background-position: 47px center in the answer sheet?

Comment: @NarenVerma Updated!